# Get current Location automatically on opening up the app

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-activity, android-studio

I'm unable to get my current location on the Google Maps Activity, I've made sure the permissions are implemented in the Android Manifest, but it still goes to 0,0 instead of my current location. On the emulator, the Location preferences are set to on.

This is my Main Activity:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class RainstormMap extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rainstorm_map);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}


private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)              getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implemente the location services!

Use the LocationListener and GoogleApiClient interfaces

```
public class RainstormMap extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;

    /**
     * Map Settings
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;

    /**
     * Map Properties and Utilities
     */
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rainstorm_map);

        mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(LOCATION_INTERVAL)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(LOCATION_INTERVAL); // 1 second, in milliseconds

        // setup map
        ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap)).getMapAsync(this);
    }

    /**
     * When get User Geo point call this method to list places by location
     *
     * @param location
     *          User current location
     */
    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        // go to user location
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude()),
                DEFAULT_ZOOM
        ));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Marker")
                .position(new LatLng(
                        location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude()));


    }

    /**
     * --------- Google API Connection and get Map if is ready ---------
     */

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location loc = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mApiClient);

        if (loc != null) {
            handleNewLocation(loc);
        } else {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(Const.TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        //TODO connection suspended implement
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    /**
     * --------- Activity Life Cycle ---------
     */

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_rainstorm_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootView">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/googleMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="ftag_google_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Code compiles correctly, thank you. It just doesn't show my location still or the marker. I do get the location button but it won't go to my location.